# Size limit of an IOS Application & Data it stores on device

Tags: iphone, ios

Developing an IOS application to play videos,video download from server.
During Installation time app size is below 20 MB,After installation user can download videos file (size 512 MB) from server through WiFi connection.

I need to download around 5 videos.

Is there any size limitation ? or depending on devices available storage space?

Comment: as far as I know, the only limitation is the device's storage space for storing files downloaded by apps.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra this question differs from those. It is about all app data including user documents I guess, not just an app itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no limitations.

User will get an alert when free space is less than 200 MB and at 0 MB.

And your app will crash when you fill all device memory and try to write more.

Answer (score 11):

No limit as far as I know.

But be aware that all files you download and store in the app have to be marked as "do not backup in iCloud" - otherwise Apple will reject your binary when you submit it to the store.

See
[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) and
[Excluding files from iCloud Backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093774/excluding-files-from-icloud-backup)